# Javascript check box validation and length

Tags: javascript, validation, dom

Have check boxes 1-300. This JS function alerts user when nothing is selected. Function works great for the first 290 elements. For example, when item 291 is selected it alerts that nothing is selected. document.checks.user.length is coming out to 298, not sure why that is either. Any suggestions? Thanks.

```
function sub_delete() //Submit & Validation for delete 
{  
    alert ( document.checks.user.length); 298?

    for (i = 0; i < document.checks.user.length; i++) //for all check boxes
    {
        if (document.checks.elements[i].name == "user" && document.checks.elements[i].checked == true ) //otherwise elements also looks at radio buttons 
        {
            document.checks.submit();
            return 0;
        }
    }

    //If we get here no delete was (true) selected
    alert ( "Select Data to Delete" );
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: That section wasn't formatted because it wasn't considered 'code'. You probably have to press space or tab before the text (as is automatically done when you click the 'Code' icon'.

Comment: What's your markup look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not looking at the same thing you're looping over.

```
for (i = 0; i < document.checks.user.length; i++) //for all check boxes
{
    if (document.checks.user[i].name == "user" && document.checks.user[i].checked == true ) //otherwise elements also looks at radio buttons 
    {
            document.checks.submit();
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Try that instead.

For this many elements it's probably best not to recalculate .length each time, too.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know I could index by name of input "user[i]". I took this line out no longer makes sense, document.checks.user[i].name == "user" ( my html <input type=checkbox name="user" value="'$NAME'" ID="Checkbox1"> <input type=checkbox name="user" value="'$NAME'" ID="Checkbox2" )

Answer (score 1):

You're iterating over the elements of document.checks.user, however you're checking document.checks.elements[i] for name and value ('checked-ness').